# I am getting error about webkit keyframes in Css section in my project

Tags: css

I am getting this error and the animation is not working properly:

> Always define standard rule '@keyframes' when defining keyframes."

[image: CSS Lint Error]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please add code and data as text ([using code formatting](//stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code)), not images. Images: A) don't allow us to copy-&-paste the code/errors/data for testing; B) don't permit searching based on the code/error/data contents; and [many more reasons](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557). Images should only be used, in addition to text in code format, if having the image adds something significant that is not conveyed by just the text code/error/data.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's telling you to use the web standard [@keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes) definition. However, in the example you've provided you're using [@-webkit-keyframes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-animation) which is non-standard.

To fix the error you need to change `@-webkit-keyframes` to `@keyframes`. Furthermore, you can find the browser support of the standard `@keyframes` definition on [Can I Use? @keyframes](https://caniuse.com/?search=%40keyframes)